# jQuery chart controls for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, charts

I would like to know some good jQuery chart controls which can be integrated with my ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[6 jQuery Chart Plugins For Your App](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/)

[flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

> Flot is a pure Javascript plotting
>   library for jQuery. It produces
>   graphical plots of arbitrary datasets
>   on-the-fly client-side.

[jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)

> This jQuery plugin generates
>   sparklines (small inline charts)
>   directly in the browser using data
>   supplied either inline in the HTML, or
>   via javascript.

[jQuery Google Charts 1.0](http://www.maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/#1)

[jQuery Chart Plugin version 0.1](http://www.reach1to1.com/sandbox/jquery/jqchart/)

[jQchart](http://jsgt.org/lib/jquery/plugin/jqchart/sample/v003/test-use-gradient.html)

[TufteGraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about which JQuery Chart Controls is suitable for your application but if you're using ASP.NET 3.5 (SP1). You can use Microsoft Chart Controls (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart). I would like to advise you to download the sample application and try them out. It's absolutely worth trying.